# ¿Por qué no funciona setTimeout en jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

lo que quiero que haga la función es:

1. Al hacer hover en BotonMenu1 se establezca el menu1 y 2 en display flex y opacity 1.
2. Al quitar el hover de BotonMenu1, el menu1 y 2 se establezcan con opacity 0 y top 0.
3. Que luego de pasar 700ms (tiempo suficiente para que se realice una animación), se ejecute el display none para el menu1 y 2.

```js
$('.botonMenu1').hover(function(){
    $('.menu1, .menu2').css('display', 'flex');
    $('.menu1, .menu2').animate({'opacity': '1', 'top': '51px'}, 0);
}, function(){
    $('.menu1, .menu2').animate({'opacity': '0', 'top': '0'}, 0, 
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.menu1, .menu2').css('display', 'none')
    }, 700))
});
```

Pero por algun motivo, al hacer hover en el BotonMenu1, funciona correctamente el paso 1 pero luego de los 700ms se aplica solo el paso 2 y 3, como si hubiera quitado el hover.

¡EDIT! ---

Lo único que quiero es que la segunda linea de este código (display none) se ejecute con un delay de 300ms para que se llegue a ver una animación antes de desaparecer, por algun motivo, el setTimeout hace que funcione mal.

```js
$('.site-home-header, .contenido').hover(function(){
    $('.menu-sub').css({'opacity': '0', 'top': '-20px'});
    $('.menu-sub').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: Pon `() =>` justo delante de `setTimeout` y funcionará

Comment: Intente poner eso por todos lados adelante de setTimeout pero no funciona, si pongo ()=> directamente. está mal el codigo, y si lo pongo sin el () es como si lo anulara. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que tratando de reproducir el problema en mi respuesta no tengo ningún tipo de inconveniente, tal vez el `setTimeout()` no está ubicado en el mejor lugar pero esencialmente no hay ningún problema en la ejecución.

**Cosas que cambié *(por si no las habías tomado en cuenta)***:

- Agregué Jquery al script, que no lo tienes en tu fiddle.
- Cambie la función `animate` por `css` y en el archivo css coloqué la animación (es básicamente lo mismo y mejor).
- Agregue un html para probar.

**Mira el ejemplo**:

```js
$('.botonMenu1').hover(function(){
    $('.menu1, .menu2').css('display', 'flex');
    console.log($('.menu1, .menu2').css('display'))
    $('.menu1, .menu2').css({'opacity': '1', 'top': '51px'}, 0);
}, function(){
    $('.menu1, .menu2').css({'opacity': '0', 'top': '0'}, 0, 
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.menu1, .menu2').css('display', 'none');
        console.log($('.menu1, .menu2').css('display'));
    }, 700))
});
```

```css
.menu1 {
  display: none;
  transition: .2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="botonMenu1">
  Boton
</button>

<div class="menu1">menu</div>
```

> EDIT:

**Tal vez te siente mejor trabajar con css, te dejo un ejemplo**:

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #202225;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: auto 0;
  transition: .2s;
}

h3 {
  color: #202225;
}

p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}


#foo1 {
  transition: .2s;
  background-color: white;;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 70px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 70px;
  border-top-left-radius: 70px;
  border-top-right-radius: 70px;
}

#foo2 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  transition: .2s;
  margin-top: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#foo1:hover + #foo2{
  margin-top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}

#foo1:hover {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  margin-top: -60px;
}
```

```html
<div id=wrapper>
  <div id="foo1">
  <h3>Mostrar</h3>
</div>
<div id="foo2"><p>Pickaboo!</p></div>
</div>
```

**Solución**:

El problema se soluciona con un clearTimeout, es raro y no recuerdo que me pasara nunca, imagino que es por lo obsoleto que está Jquery y como este manejan los eventos, tal vez es por cambios en JS... (es mi teoría nada mas, no me he tomado el tiempo de averiguar) igual la gente debería de ir dejando JQuery, ya no es productivo ni dedicarle tiempo a aprenderlo, igual por nostalgia y para salir del paso cuela tal vez.

**Mira el ejemplo con JQuery**:

```js
var time;

$("#foo1").on("mouseover", () => {
 clearTimeout(time)
 $("#foo2").css({"display":"flex"})
 $("#foo2").css({"margin-top": "0px", "opacity": 1});
});

$("#foo1").on("mouseout", () => {
 $("#foo2").css({"margin-top": "20px", "opacity": 0});
  time = setTimeout(() => {
   $("#foo2").hide();
    console.log($("#foo2").css("display"))
  },700)
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #202225;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: auto 0;
  transition: .2s;
}

h3 {
  color: #202225;
}

p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}


#foo1 {
  transition: .2s;
  background-color: white;;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 70px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 70px;
  border-top-left-radius: 70px;
  border-top-right-radius: 70px;
}

#foo2 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  transition: .2s;
  margin-top: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#foo1:hover {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  margin-top: -60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=wrapper>
  <div id="foo1">
  <h3>Mostrar</h3>
</div>
<div id="foo2"><p>Pickaboo!</p></div>
</div>
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: Después de intentar e intentar, incluso con el codigo que me pasaste, me di cuenta que el problema es el setTimeout, por algún motivo, se ejecuta aunque no se cumpla la condición, si saco el setTimeout y dejo el display none normal, funciona correctamente, el problema es que al ejecutarse inmediatamente no se llega a ver la animación. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Voy a editar el post y voy a agregar el simple trozo de codigo que quiero que se ejecute con delay.

Comment: Amigo pero me parece que en el ejemplo se ejecuta sin ningún tipo de problema, para eso añadí los logs para que veas que efectivamente el display cambia a none después del tiempo esperado, igual estoy atento.

Comment: El tema es que tengo un codigo un poco largo y la función es un poco mas compleja, pero seria mucho para ponerlo acá. Ahí edite el post.